# jQuery getting undefined data-value from appended span

Tags: jquery

so I add span after the 'li' and when clicked I'd like to get the data-value of the closest 'li' and its child 'img'. For some reason I'm getting undefined.

```
<div id="mi-slider" class="mi-slider">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img data-value="1" src="images/1.jpg" alt="img01"><h4>Boots</h4></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img data-value="2" src="images/2.jpg" alt="img02"><h4>Oxfords</h4></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img data-value="3" src="images/3.jpg" alt="img03"><h4>Loafers</h4></a></li>                            
</ul>
</div>

$(".mi-slider ul:first-child li").after('<span class="aff_delete">X</span>');

// delete product
$( ".aff_delete" ).click( function() {
    // product id
    var id = $(this).closest('li').children('img').attr('data-value');          
    alert(id);       
});
```

[See here](https://jsfiddle.net/nmu4epqg/)
When you click the x you will get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `prev()` since the `span` is a sibling and `find` since the `img` is a nested child

```js
$(".mi-slider ul:first-child li").after('<span class="aff_delete">X</span>');

// delete product
$(".aff_delete").click(function() {
  // product id
  var id = $(this).prev('li').find('img').attr('data-value');
  alert(id);
});
```

```css
.aff_delete {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mi-slider" class="mi-slider">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img data-value="1" src="images/1.jpg" alt="img01">
        <h4>Boots</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img data-value="2" src="images/2.jpg" alt="img02">
        <h4>Oxfords</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img data-value="3" src="images/3.jpg" alt="img03">
        <h4>Loafers</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```